# Inequality olympiad

Tags: inequality, contest-math

For all positive numbers $a,b,c$, prove that 
$$\frac{a^3}{b^2-bc+c^2}+\frac{b^3}{a^2-ac+c^2}+\frac{c^3}{a^2-ab+b^2}\geq 3 \frac{(ab+bc+ac)}{a+b+c}$$

Note that both side are homogeneous of degree 1, so I think it is safe to assume $a+b+c=1$ but this does not go very far.

Any ideas/hint?
Thanks

Comment: The LHS terms can be rewritten as $\frac{a^3(b+c)}{b^3+c^3}$. Not sure if that would help.

Comment: @Element118, good caught, I made some calculation error

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By Cauchy-Schwarz inequality:
$$\sum_{\text{cyc}}\dfrac{a^3}{b^2-bc+c^2}\left(\sum_{\text{cyc}}a\left(b^2-bc+c^2\right)\right)\ge \left(a^2+b^2+c^2\right)^2$$
In fact, you can prove the following stronger inequality:
$$\frac{\left(a^2+b^2+c^2\right)^2}{\sum_{\text{cyc}}a\left(b^2-bc+c^2\right)}\ge a+b+c\ge3\dfrac{ab+bc+ac}{a+b+c}$$
This holds:
$$\iff \left(a^2+b^2+c^2\right)^2\ge (a+b+c)\sum_{\text{cyc}}a\left(b^2-bc+c^2\right)$$
$$\iff a^4+b^4+c^4+abc(a+b+c)\ge ab\left(a^2+b^2\right)+bc\left(b^2+c^2\right)+ac\left(a^2+c^2\right)$$
The last step is true by [Schur's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur%27s_inequality), where $t=2$.

Comment: Why is $a+b+c\geq 3(\frac{ab+bc+ac}{a+b+c}$

Comment: is that an arrangement inequality?

Comment: @amathnerd $3(ab+bc+ca)\leq a^2+b^2+c^2+2ab+2bc+2ca=(a+b+c)^2$

Comment: @Element118 Exactly what I thought! Thank you so much

Comment: You mean "where $t=2$". I've edited it.